# package names convention in Spring

Tags: java, spring, package, layer

I'm developing  Spring aplication with SpringMVC, Hibernate and other stuff. I know where to put classes like services, controllers, models, daos but i wonder how to name a package with objects to validation and it's validators.

Is there any standard name convention to these classes? 
Are there other conventional names for packages except those mentioned above for some other kinds of classes?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 0):

I follow the SonarCube convention for package names to match the regex:

```
"^[a-z]+(\\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$"
```

eg.

```
package org.Something; // Non-Compliant   
package org.something; // Compliant
```